# OpenCV wasm build errors

Tags: opencv, webassembly

After adding `libopencv_imgcodecs.a` to use the `imdecode` method I am seeing the following errors. I built all the latest opencv libs for wasm.

```
em++ -msimd128 -I. -I../opencv/include/ -I ../opencv/include -I ../modules/video/include -I ../modules/flann/include -I ../modules/core/include -I ../modules/stitching/include -I ../modules/imgproc/include -I ../modules/objdetect/include -I ../modules/gapi/include -I ../modules/world/include -I ../modules/ml/include -I ../modules/imgcodecs/include -I ../modules/dnn/include -I ../modules/dnn/src/vkcom/include -I ../modules/dnn/src/ocl4dnn/include -I ../modules/dnn/src/tengine4dnn/include -I ../modules/videoio/include -I ../modules/highgui/include -I ../modules/features2d/include -I ../modules/ts/include -I ../modules/photo/include -I ../modules/calib3d/include ../opencv/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_core.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_dnn.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_features2d.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_flann.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_objdetect.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_photo.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_video.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a ../opencv/lib/libopencv_videoio.a ../bindings.cpp ../helloopencv.cpp --bind --no-entry -o helloopencv.js -s WASM=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=1 -s EXPORT_NAME=createModule -s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_stream_default_create
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_stream_set_user_data
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_stream_set_user_data_length
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_stream_set_read_function
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_stream_set_skip_function
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_stream_set_seek_function
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_stream_destroy
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_stream_create_default_file_stream
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_stream_destroy
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_create_decompress
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_destroy_codec
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_set_default_decoder_parameters
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_setup_decoder
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_read_header
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_image_destroy
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_set_error_handler
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_set_warning_handler
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_decode
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_set_default_encoder_parameters
wasm-ld: error: ../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp.o): undefined symbol: opj_image_create
```

Any help to solve this issue is appreciated. This is the first time I am trying to work on web assembly so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, did you find a solution @Didas?